# If no parent object is specified in the call, what is the default value for findobj()?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, figure, subfigure

In MatLab, if we write `findobj(gca,'Type','line')` then `findobj` will return a handle toa list  the children of the current axis whose `Type` is `line`. However, what if we do not specify the parent object as `gca` and simply write `findobj('Type','line')`? Does this look search through all objects in the current work-space? search through all children of the current figure (`gcf`)? What exactly is the search space if you do not bother to pass in a reference to a parent object?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify an object or array of objects to restrict the search to (as the first argument), then [`findobj`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html) will search through the [root object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/groot.html) and all of its descendants (i.e. everything).

Note that `findobj` will not find objects with [hidden handles](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/preventing-access-to-figures-and-axes.html). You should use [`findall`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findall.html) for that.